# Connect to SQL Server using SAS 9.3

Tags: sql-server, odbc, sas

I am trying to link to an online SQL Server (2008) using SAS 9.3 on Windows7.

I've got an example:

```
LIBNAME DB1 ODBC DSN="DB1" schema=dbo;
```

Thus I imitated and wrote:

```
LIBNAME DB2 ODBC DSN="DB2" schema=dbo;
```

When I run the example, it works well. But when I run my code, I've got following error:

> ERROR: CLI error trying to establish connection: [Microsoft][ODBC
>   Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
>
> ERROR: Error in the LIBNAME statement.

I've checked my `ODBC` settings, and `DB1` and `DB2` all appear in the `System DSN` tab. The only difference is that the `Driver` of the database that the example link to is `SQL Server Native Client 10.0`, while the database my code link to is `SQL Server Native Client 11.0`.

May I know how to make my code work? Any clue will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No problem anymore. I found that the name of the ODBC and the database are not consistent. In fact, one has to address ODBC name in SAS rather than database name.

Suppose the database is `DB1`, and the ODBC is `database1`, then the code should be:

```
LIBNAME database1 ODBC DSN="database1" schema=dbo;
```